# How to add href route in blade for multi language?

Tags: multilingual, laravel-6

So I have creted my group in web.php

```
Route::redirect('/', '/it');

Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {


    Route::get('/','HomeController@index');

    Route::get('/business', 'BusinessViewController@index');
    Route::post('business', 'BusinessViewController@store');
    Route::get('/business/create', 'BusinessViewController@create');
    Route::get('/business/{slug}', 'BusinessViewController@show');

    Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index');

});
```

Also created the middleware SetLanguage.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setLocale($request->segment(1));
    URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

I addeed the middleware class to middlewareGroups - "web" in Kernal.php
Now how should I add href links in blade.php?

`<a href="/business">{{__('common.list')}}</a>`  This line does not bring to correct language.

I do not want session, I want that the language is in the url:
www.weburl.com**/en/**something

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution, what you need to route the link. so like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('contact', app()->getLocale()) }}">{{__('common.contact_us')}}</a>
```

and to work this you have to add the name to the Route in web.php like this:

```
Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index')->name('contact');
```

if you do not add the name, it will say Route not found.